# Cannot compile 7zip under MSVC2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 7zip

I cannot compile 7zip under MSVC2012.

When i type:

```
C:\7zsrc> nmake NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1 Build.mak
```

I get this:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    link  -nologo -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF /LARGEADDRESSAWARE -out:O\   oleaut32.li
b ole32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'O\'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
Stop.
```

What should i do to compile it? i tried checking in google but i didn't found anything related to this problem...

Also, here's Build.mak from 7zip souce package:

```
LIBS = $(LIBS) oleaut32.lib ole32.lib

!IFDEF CPU
!IFNDEF NO_BUFFEROVERFLOWU
LIBS = $(LIBS) bufferoverflowU.lib
 !ENDIF
!ENDIF


!IFNDEF O
!IFDEF CPU
 O=$(CPU)
!ELSE
 O=O
!ENDIF
!ENDIF

!IF "$(CPU)" == "AMD64"
MY_ML = ml64 -Dx64
!ELSEIF "$(CPU)" == "ARM"
MY_ML = armasm
!ELSE
MY_ML = ml
!ENDIF


!IFDEF UNDER_CE
RFLAGS = $(RFLAGS) -dUNDER_CE
!IFDEF MY_CONSOLE
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) /ENTRY:mainACRTStartup
!ENDIF
!ELSE
!IFNDEF NEW_COMPILER
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS)
!ENDIF
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -Gr
LIBS = $(LIBS) user32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib
!ENDIF

!IF "$(CPU)" == "ARM"
COMPL_ASM = $(MY_ML) $** $O/$(*B).obj
!ELSE
 COMPL_ASM = $(MY_ML) -c -Fo$O/ $**
!ENDIF

CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -nologo -c -Fo$O/ -WX -EHsc -Gy -GR-

!IFDEF MY_STATIC_LINK
!IFNDEF MY_SINGLE_THREAD
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -MT
!ENDIF
!ELSE
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -MD
!ENDIF

!IFDEF NEW_COMPILER
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -W4 -GS- -Zc:forScope
!ELSE
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -W3
!ENDIF

CFLAGS_O1 = $(CFLAGS) -O1
CFLAGS_O2 = $(CFLAGS) -O2

LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) -nologo -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF

!IFNDEF UNDER_CE
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
!ENDIF

!IFDEF DEF_FILE
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) -DLL -DEF:$(DEF_FILE)
!ENDIF

PROGPATH = $O\$(PROG)

COMPL_O1   = $(CC) $(CFLAGS_O1) $**
COMPL_O2   = $(CC) $(CFLAGS_O2) $**
COMPL_PCH  = $(CC) $(CFLAGS_O1) -Yc"StdAfx.h" -Fp$O/a.pch $**
COMPL      = $(CC) $(CFLAGS_O1) -Yu"StdAfx.h" -Fp$O/a.pch $**

all: $(PROGPATH)

clean:
-del /Q $(PROGPATH) $O\*.exe $O\*.dll $O\*.obj $O\*.lib $O\*.exp $O\*.res $O\*.pch

$O:
if not exist "$O" mkdir "$O"

$(PROGPATH): $O $(OBJS) $(DEF_FILE)
link $(LFLAGS) -out:$(PROGPATH) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

!IFNDEF NO_DEFAULT_RES
$O\resource.res: $(*B).rc
rc $(RFLAGS) -fo$@ $**
!ENDIF
$O\StdAfx.obj: $(*B).cpp
$(COMPL_PCH)
```

Comment: Does the `-out:O\` parameter make sense?

Comment: No, i tried setting PROGPATH variable to path where my source code is, nothing changesd.

Comment: What I meant (even though I'm no expert) is that I think this parameter is wrong. What does `O\` mean? Again, I may be the one mistaken here... Try searching for the `-out` switch.

Comment: It's in the make file. You need to define a target (CPU), so it knows what libraries to use (and what type executable to output).

Comment: Mister Ken White, i defined it (CPU=AMD64) but it still shows the same error LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'AMD64\'

Comment: I don't have the source for 7zip available, but there's typically a readme file or a build notes file (or instructions on the project web site) that give you specific instructions for each platform and compiler. Did you check for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Brian Wilson's guide](http://www.ski-epic.com/2012_compiling_7zip_on_windows_with_visual_studio_10/index.html) shows how to do this. The guide is for VS2010, but it worked fine for me in VS2012.

The main steps:

- Set up the environment variables using "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
- Edit C:\7zsrc\CPP\Build.mak to remove "-OPT:NOWIN98" from line 34
- Run C:\7zsrc\CPP\7zip\nmake NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1

Note the third step targets the makefile in the 7zip subdirectory instead of the Build.mak that you are targeting.

A number of executable are created. You may be interested in C:\7zsrc\CPP\7zip\UI\Client7z\O\7z.exe

Answer (score 1):

You must compile some "makefile" instead.